# Ansible task to generate and execute file using dict, template

Tags: ansible

I cant quite wrap my head around how to tell Ansible to do the following:

1. Loop over the dictionary 'users' defined in /vars/main.yml
2. Fill the template defined in /templates/sql_template.j2
3. Execute a command with the generated file as an argument

When I run the playbook, I can see in the output that each item in the dictionary is being used. When its done, the file contains the last item.

I have two options at this point:

1. execute my sql command using the generated file for each iteration.
2. somehow make each iteration add to the file instead of overwriting it and then execute the sql command using the completed file when the loop is done

Option 1 would look something like this, but it fails because of the extra command in the task

```
---
- name: Insert web app users
  template:
    src: sql_template.j2
    dest: /tmp/sql_template
  with_dict: users
  command: cat /tmp/sql_template
```

I dont have any idea how to solve for Option 2.

These are the files I currently have that write each iteration to a file on the target server. Not quite what I need, but its close.

tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Insert web app users
  template:
    src: sql_template.j2
    dest: /tmp/sql_template
  with_dict: users
```

vars/main.yml

```
users:
  test1:
    user_nbr: 500
    user_name: "test1"
    user_desc: "developer"
    password: "f0dd960681eca16f0f5c1cda8d83e72c"
    display_name: "Test1"
    email: "test1@teset.com"
  test2:
    user_nbr: 501
    user_name: "test2"
    user_desc: "developer"
    password: "f0dd960681eca16f0f5c1cda8d83e72c"
    display_name: "Test2"
    email: "test2@test.com"
```

templates/sql_template.j2

```
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users (user_nbr, user_name, user_desc, password, user_timeout, suspended, change_password, no_password_expiry, display_name, email) VALUES ({{item.value.user_nbr}}, '{{item.value.user_name}}', '{{item.value.user_desc}}', '{{ item.value.password}}', 60, 0, 0, 1, '{{ item.value.display_name}}', '{{ item.value.email}}' );
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users_orgs (user_nbr, org_nbr, class_nbr, primary_org) VALUES({{item.value.user_nbr}}, 1000, -1, 1);
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users_orgs (user_nbr, org_nbr, class_nbr, primary_org) SELECT {{ item.value.user_nbr}}, org_nbr, -1, 0 FROM orgs WHERE org_nbr != 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do the looping inside the template. The variables defined in the file vars/main.yml are automatically available in the template. The files now look like this and it generates the entire file:

tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Insert web app users
  template:
    src: sql_template.j2
    dest: /tmp/sql_template
```

templates/sql_template.j2

```
{% for item in users %}
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users (user_nbr, user_name, user_desc, password, user_timeout, suspended, change_password, no_password_expiry, display_name, email) VALUES ({{users[item].user_nbr}}, '{{users[item].user_name}}', '{{users[item].user_desc}}', '{{ users[item].password}}', 60, 0, 0, 1, '{{ users[item].display_name}}', '{{ users[item].email}}' );
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users_orgs (user_nbr, org_nbr, class_nbr, primary_org) VALUES({{users[item].user_nbr}}, 1000, -1, 1);
INSERT INTO cbcommon:users_orgs (user_nbr, org_nbr, class_nbr, primary_org) SELECT {{ users[item].user_nbr}}, org_nbr, -1, 0 FROM orgs WHERE org_nbr != 1000;
{% endfor %}
```